# jwplayer uncaught exception in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, jwplayer

I'm trying to implement jwplayer in ios app but using a very simple startup it is continuously throwing signal abort error

```
@interface ViewController () <JWPlayerDelegate>

@property JWPlayerController *player;

@end

@implementation ViewController

 - (void)viewDidLoad
   {
[super viewDidLoad];
[self createPlayer];


}

- (void)createPlayer
{

JWConfig *config = [JWConfig configWithContentURL:@"http://content.bitsontherun.com/videos/3XnJSIm4-injeKYZS.mp4"];
config.autostart = YES;
self.player = [[JWPlayerController alloc] initWithConfig:config];

config.size = CGSizeMake(100, 100);
_player.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
[self.view addSubview:self.view];
}
@end
```

Error:

> jwplayercheck[4111:850586] -[JWConfig xmlPlayList]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1701256e0
>   2016-12-21 15:14:31.827747 jwplayercheck[4111:850586] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[JWConfig xmlPlayList]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1701256e0'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x1820321c0 0x180a6c55c 0x182039278 0x182036278 0x181f3059c 0x1000e38bc 0x1000be750 0x1000b4f68 0x1000b4a00 0x1000d9770 0x1000d97e0 0x1000ab850 0x1000ab7c4 0x187e860b0 0x187e85c78 0x187e8c424 0x187e898c4 0x187efc0e8 0x188108a78 0x18810e5c8 0x188122e60 0x18810b5ac 0x183bd98bc 0x183bd9728 0x183bd9ad0 0x181fe0278 0x181fdfbc0 0x181fdd7c0 0x181f0c048 0x187ef12b0 0x187eec034 0x1000ac414 0x180ef05b8)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
>   (lldb)

Comment: Could you show the whole error message? That could help.

Comment: please check the post again, i've mentioned the error code as well

Comment: The exception is not related to the posted code. The crucial information in the error message is the bold part after **reason**.

Comment: but there isn't any xml list included in the code or else

Answer (score 2):

[Change Other Linker Flags on Build Setting to "-all_load"]